# How many flips does a tossed macroscopic coin need to go through until the coinflip's result becomes indeterministic?

Tags: chaos-theory, stochastic-processes, randomness

A coinflip is a macroscopic event and is deterministic in nature. A coin-flipping machine that operates at the greatest physical precision possible would be able to predict the coinflip's result (based on the arbitrary tossing force chosen) instantly without having to wait for the coin to land.

Is this prediction capability true no matter how high the coin is tossed? Or is there a fundamental limit to how high the coin can be tossed and still be 100% predictable? If there is a limit, it would be due to quantum-level noise being amplified over the coin's journey. Is this a valid model? The Compton wavelength for a standard US quarter is way below the Planck length. This leads me to assume that a coin flip is perfectly predictable no matter how high it is tossed. But at the same time, I don't think a coin needs to rely on its Compton wavelength to 'seed' the indeterminacy of the final coinflip result. At the limit, we have something like [Lyapunov Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_time) that says true indeterminacy *is* eventually achieved.

If a macroscopic coinflip CAN become indeterminate, then at what point does it do so; how many flips of the coin are necessary in any given cointoss in order to achieve a fundamentally indeterminate coinflip result?

Comment: I do not think this can be answered , it will depend on the errors in all the components that enter, and any machine will have errors. (classically, quantum mechanics cannot enter this macroscopic experiment nothing can be modeled with a single coherent wavefunction)

Comment: Flip a single coin once without giving it any impressive height at all. There is an absurdly small chance that it will touch the moon instead of the ground.

Comment: @annav, I mentioned that the cointossing machine is as physically precise as possible, so only fundamental uncertainty should be considered. I think the problem IS answerable by finding at what energy quantity does the coin need to be launched at such that the Energy's conjugate variable Delta Time (in the uncertainty principle) multiplied by the coin's flight time, equals the time it takes the coin to make a single full rotation.

Comment: BTW, why do you consider the Compton wavelength of any significance here? Do you think that light that scatters at the coin has more influence than the surrounding air? Or did you mean de-Broglie wavelength? Then this would be orders of magnitude larger (depending on speed of the coin) than Compton wavelength, but still very small, of course.

Comment: @oliver, yes the de-Broglie wavelength, sorry. Just using the uncertainty principle, where the coin mass is 0.00567kg, and the perfect certainty precision at Planck Length, then the uncertainty of the coin's velocity is 500m/s. Which is more than enough to cause a human-flipped coin flip to have an indeterminate result.But a human can't achieve such a position certainty before launching the coin.

Comment: How does your coin-flipping machine make precision measurements of all the air molecules in the vicinity? I suppose it also needs a high precision map of the local gravitation field, too.

Comment: The title of your question is only asking how many times the coin can be tossed. Now, as each toss is by definition an independent event, the number of tosses should be irrelevant here.

Comment: The de Broglie wavelength, that is an envelope of the mathematically strict Heisenberg uncertainty at the quantum level,  for the  mass of a coin, is so tiny no machine could measure it ! see for example this  https://www.doubtnut.com/question-answer-chemistry/the-de-broglie-wavelength-of-a-particle-with-mass-1-g-and-velocity-100-m-sec-is-12225393 . The quantum only in special cases can be seen in the macroscopic frame ( superconductivity for example ),

Comment: I'd really expect the classical, statistical-mechanical pressure fluctuations to be substantially larger than any quantum fluctuations in this system.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention quantum noise, it should already be clear to you that the coin-flip is principally indeterminate like any other physical process. But just like there is a difference in accuracy between the prediction whether an electron after a double slit hits the first or second order interference maximum or the prediction if the electron is going to hit the left or the right half of the screen, there are different levels of prediction accuracy as to what coin tosses bring about what result. But that level cannot just be boiled down to the number of tosses.

Suppose the coin on its flight happens to reach a perfectly symmetric equilibrium point (say stopping in mid-air, with the mid-plane parallel to ground), then the slightest turbulence in the surrounding air will decide what happens next, and this is can be sensitive to quantum fluctuations. And, not only is the equilibrium point itself sensitive to quantum fluctuations, but also the path to this point is continuously sensitive to the cummulative effects of qunatum fluctuations.

Whether the occurence of such equilibria are, so to say, a null set in configuration space, or cover a significant fraction of coin tosses, this I don't know. I suspect the former, i.e. as you say, the coin tosses are overwhelmingly determinate. You mileage may vary.

In order to get a sharper statement about quantum influence on macroscopic experiments, you would have to specify your experimental conditions a lot sharper. It is for a reason, that it took mankind until the beginning of the 20th century until they conceived experiments that clearly show quantum effects: it is comparatively difficult.

Comment: A scenario where a machine simply drops a vertical coin is going to be much quicker to reach true indeterminism, but I'm interested in regular cointosses. In a regular cointoss, the coin remains out of angular equilibrium for the duration of its flight. Quantum noise in the air is going to take much longer to affect the result.

My surface level intuition is saying that the fundamental energy uncertainty of the launch due to Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle will affect the result when Delta Time times the coin's flight time equals the time it takes for the coin to make one full rotation.

Comment: I am afraid your problem is vastly underdefined. Just imagine what happens to all the 10^23 atoms in the coin, and tell me that anybody knows the answer without solving at least the Schrödinger equation for all these atoms. Either that, or just use classical mechanics/hydrodynamics and accept that indeterminacy occurs without recourse to quantum.